# Is Electronics and Robotics the best StackExchange for asking about building wiring to power my 220 volt IBM Server?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm trying to figure out which StackExchange is best for me to ask detailed questions about 220 volt wiring from the fusebox to my IBM Server.

The Electronics StackExchange appears to be the best choice at first glance, but perhaps I should ask on the Home Improvement StackExchange instead?

For an even more meta request, is meta.electronics.stackexchange.com even the right place to ask where I should be asking the question itself? :-)

Comment: [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) would be a better choice for this kind of question, most likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think if you are interested in the hobbyist approach to creating a power supply for your computer, that fits perfectly. If you want to know how to wire your house from an electricians perspective, this is a home improvement task, and a different stack exchange is probably a better fit.

Yes, this is a good place to ask if the question fits.